# How to make "class1 * class2" behave like "class2 * class1"?

Tags: python, class, oop

I've been watching [Linear Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) series made by [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw) and I came up with this idea that I should write programs to compute the math, so I started to do it.

I wrote some methods. I wrote mul method for it. This method stretch out the vector by a given factor.

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, data):
        #               [1]
        # [1, 2, 3] --> [2]
        #               [3]
        self.data = data
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError("The second object(item) is not a number(integer, float)")
        return Vector(list(map(lambda x: x * other, self.data)))
```

For example:

```
sample = Vector([1, 2])
```

When I execute this, it executes without errors:

```
print(sample * 10)
# it returns Vector([10, 20])
```

But when I execute this:

```
print(10 * sample)
```

It throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jackson/Desktop/Matrices/MM.py", line 139, in <module>
    print(10 * a)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Vector'
```

I know the second one runs int.**mul** . So is there any way for the second one to behave like the first one?? Because technically there shouldn't be any difference between "Vector * int" and "int * Vector".

Here is the full code if you need --> [link](https://codeshare.io/a3J8Jz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement `__rmul__` etc. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Also, a really good linear algebra library already exists for python called [numpy](https://www.numpy.org/) (but if you are implementing it yourself for learning purposes, just ignore that and have fun instead).